# What exactly are parentheses around an object reference doing in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, casting

I have some procedures that take `Control` object references as a parameter.

I have a bunch of `Control`s throughout my project of varying derived types such as `Button`, `TextBox`, `PictureBox`, `ListBox`, etc.

I was calling the procedure and passing the reference as normal:

`Procedure(controlRef)`

I changed some of the Warning Notifications in my project configuration. I'm guessing it was changing the Implicit Conversion Notification from 'None' to 'Warning' that caused warnings similar to the following to appear everywhere these procedures were called:

"Implicit conversion from 'Control' to 'Button' in copying the value of 'ByRef' parameter 'parControl' back to the matching argument."

This makes sense, I'm doing an Implicit Conversion, but hang on a second, I'm passing a `Button` in to a `Control` parameter, not a `Control` to a `Button` like it says, I'm slightly confused what's happening here.

Anyway, I take a look at the "Show potential fixes" and there is no fix suggestion, only Suppress or Configure options, okay. So I do a explicit cast using `DirectCast(controlRef, Control)` to see if that'll remove the warning on Implicit Conversion, which it does, but it gets replaced by a Redundant Cast warning, again, this makes sense. So I remove the cast using the potential fixes and the argument in the procedure call is left with parentheses around it and no more warnings.

`Procedure((controlRef))`

What is going on here exactly?

Comment: What's the signature of `Procedure`?

Comment: `Procedure(ByRef param As Control)`.  If I remove the `ByRef` I don't get a complaint about the implicit conversion and the parentheses around the argument are not required. I just want to know what those parens are doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the signature for `Procedure` is `Sub Procedure(ByRef param As Control)` and you're passing a `Button` to the method, the compiler is correctly warning you about an implicit conversion.

Imagine that this were the definition of `Procedure`:

```
Sub Procedure(ByRef param As Control)
    param = New Label()
End Sub
```

And if you called it this way:

```
Dim button = New Button()
Procedure(button)
```

Then you're effectively calling this code:

```
Dim button As Button = New Button()
button = New Label()
```

Hence the compiler warning.

If you change the signature to `Sub Procedure(ByVal param As Control)` then there is no possibility of assignment back to the calling variable and the warning will go away.

The use of the extra parenthesis forces the call to be `ByVal` instead of `ByRef`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-force-an-argument-to-be-passed-by-value

Comment: I only needed to know what the parens were doing but thanks.

Comment: @typedefMiles_WilliamsMILO - Your question asked for more than just the parens.

Comment: My question was "What exactly are parentheses around an object reference doing in VB.NET?" It's the title. Lol. But I do appreciate the extra info. Cheers.

Comment: @typedefMiles_WilliamsMILO - ou did say, "This makes sense, I'm doing an Implicit Conversion, but hang on a second, I'm passing a `Button` in to a `Control` parameter, not a `Control` to a `Button` like it says, I'm slightly confused what's happening here." So when you asked "What is going on here exactly?" I took that to mean all of the issues raised in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question but it may be a solution to the actual problem. It also requires significant code, so I decided an answer was the best option.

One has to wonder why you have declared that parameter `ByRef` in the first place. Many people do so when it is not required because, as in VB6, they think that it will prevent an object being copied. That is not the case because reference type objects, i.e. class instances, don't get copied when passed by value anyway. That's the whole point of reference types, i.e. the value of a variable is a reference, not an object, so passing by value only copies the reference, not the object. If you are not assigning anything to that parameter inside the method then it should be declared `ByVal`.

If you are assigning to the parameter inside the method then the solution is to declare the method to be generic. That way, the parameter won't be `Control` but will actually be the type you pass in. In its simplest form, that would be:

```vb
Private Sub Procedure(Of T)(ByRef control As T)
    '...
End Sub
```

That's probably not enough though, because that would allow you to pass any object as an argument. To restrict the method to only accept controls:

```vb
Private Sub Procedure(Of TControl As Control)(ByRef control As TControl)
    '...
End Sub
```

Now you will only be able to pass a control to the method but, inside the method, the parameter will be treated as the actual type of the argument you passed, e.g. if you pass a `Button` then `TControl` is fixed to be `Button`. If you need to create a control of the appropriate type inside the method then you need another restriction too, which enables you to assume a parameterless constructor, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub Procedure(Of TControl As {New, Control})(ByRef control As TControl)
    control = New TControl With {.Location = New Point(100, 100),
                                 .Size = New Size(50, 25)}

    '...
End Sub
```

That code means that, inside the method, you know that the type of the parameter is `Control` or derived from that type and that you can create new instances by invoking a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Not originally my code. Maintaining an old application. I was in the process of going through and removing all the ByRefs as I come across this actually. Like I said, when it's removed there was no issue. I just wanted to know what the parens were doing because the searches I did using VB.Net and parentheses weren't providing any answers. And yes, the person who wrote this was a VB6 programmer. So what you said makes sense.

Comment: For the record, I just did a Bing search for *"vb.net argument in parentheses"* and the page linked to in the accepted answer was the third result. No guarantee that you would have known that that was what you were looking for unless you read it but I would hope that you'd read the third result. Personally, I find Bing better for .NET development than Google, which did not return that same result. It did return [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?874517) though. It's for VB6 but the answer is the same for both languages. Not sure what you searched for.

Comment: Interesting. You are correct. Didn't get that with Google. I first tried looking at the VB Language Reference and didn't see anything, then Google and didn't see anything either. Just a bunch of stuff about VBA and the Call Function and needing to include parens with VB.NET. I will be sure to keep Bing in mind next time I have a microsoft related search. Also, I didn't know that it had anything to do with it being an argument as well. I was just looking for matches with things like object, reference,  parentheses, vb.net. It's easier to find things when you know what you're looking for ;)